# how to solve error in page number order in latex?

Tags: latex, overleaf, page-numbering

I am writing a paper based on Elsevier's two-column latex class.
The page number is shown in the picture below:
page x of y (but x > y)!! It shows page 13 of 11!!

This is the problem that I need to solve.

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{cas-dc}
```

[image]

Comment: From which point on is the page numbering incorrect? Do you have 13 or 11 pages in total? If you plan to submit it to a journal, then the editor will probably take care of the page numbers, otherwise you can do `\cleardoublepage` followed by a `\setcounter{page}{1}` to change the page numbering.

Comment: I have 13 pages in total. But the last page shows 13 of 11!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe just run LaTeX another time. While it's typesetting the first page, it doesn't yet know how many pages there will be. Once it's finished, it stores that information in some separate file, where it will be read from upon the next run.

For example, if the `lastpage` package is used, there will be a warning the first time you run it:

```
Package lastpage Warning: Rerun to get the references right on input line 14.
```

Comment: I re-loaded and re-ran Latex several times, as well as added \usepackage{lastpage}, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Then you will need to provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example before anyone can help you further.